Arrays, Pointers and Memory addresses instances confusion in C++
I'm learning and playing a bit with pointers and memory addresses.
The thing is that I've tried doing some moves with instances inside arrays and getting their memory address, and I can't figure out why the following case is not fulfilled if they are supposed to point to the same instance, so I should get the same address.
I would really like to know why this happens, since I think that by calling the address pointed to by the pointer associated with the array, I would be calling the same memory address of the original instance, not a different address of the array.
If there is any confusion or misunderstanding with my question, please feel free to ask anything to understand my problem. I really want to know why this is happening.
Code:
#include<iostream>

#include<string.h>

using namespace std;

class Student {
    int age;
    string name;

    // methods and public variables
    public: Student(int _age, string _name) {
        this -> age = _age;
        this -> name = _name;
    }

    // getters & setters not appearing in this problem
};

int main() {

    Student a1(12, "qwe");
    Student a2(15, "rty");
    Student a3(17, "zxc");
    Student * p = & a1;

    // array of instances
    Student students[] = {
        a1,
        a2,
        a3
    };

    // arrays with pointers
    Student * studentPtr1 = students;
    Student * studentPtr2 = & students[0];

    // this two are the same memory addres
    cout << "&a1 --> " << & a1 << endl;
    cout << "p --> " << p << endl;
    // the rest of these memory addresses are different from a1 but are the same memory address as each other
    cout << "&(students[0]) --> " << & (students[0]) << endl;
    cout << "&(students) :" << & (students) << endl;
    cout << "&(*studentPtr1) --> " << & ( * studentPtr1) << endl;
    cout << "&(*studentPtr2) --> " << & ( * studentPtr2) << endl;
    cout << "studentPtr2 --> " << studentPtr2 << endl;

    // if students[0] is a1 why if a try to get his memory address i get a different one ?.
    // &(students[0]) == &a1 ---> false (why??).

    return 0;
}

Output
&a1 --> 0x7ffeb1d77e30  
p --> 0x7ffeb1d77e30  
&(students[0]) --> 0x7ffeb1d77ec0  
&(students) :0x7ffeb1d77ec0  
&(*studentPtr1) --> 0x7ffeb1d77ec0  
&(*studentPtr2) --> 0x7ffeb1d77ec0  
studentPtr2 --> 0x7ffeb1d77ec0  


what other output did you expect and why?

an object that is stored in the array cannot be the same object that is not in the array. c++ has value semantics. Student students[] = { a1, a2, a3 }; is making copies

OT: std::string is from <string>. <string.h> is something completely different

You could have an array of pointers to objects stored elsewhere and be able to add and shuffle around those pointers very quickly, almost everything else you will do with the array will be slower because the CPU  has to use the pointer to look up where the object really is and then very likely will have to load it into cache. But if the objects are directly in the array, they are all in a nice straight line in memory and modern CPUs are disgustingly good at predicting, reading ahead, caching and generally being very fast when data is in a straight line.

if students[0] is a1...  It's not.  It's a copy of a1.

That deleteStudent member function is not a good idea. If you have a pointer to a Student object you would ordinarily delete the Student object with delete ptr;.

What reference taught you to use this-> syntax?  You don't need it.  If you are going to use it, you should apply it everywhere; be consistent.  Your constructor should use an initialization list instead of this->.

Your destructor should be empty.  You have no dynamic variables and nothing that cleans up.  The delete operator is used for items allocated in dynamic memory, which you don't have.  You have no idea if the User of your class used local allocation or dynamic allocation.  So, get rid of the delete this statement.

You should move your setName() method to the getters and setters section since it is a setter.

FYI, pass the std::string variable by reference or if it's not written to, pass it by const reference.  Otherwise the compiler will make a copy of the caller's string and pass the copy to your methods.  That's a lot of unnecessary copying, especially for large strings.

student[0] and a1 have the same value, this is true. But they are stored in different locations so their addresses are different.
Here's another example
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int c = 3;
int student[3] = { a, b, c };

Now student[0] == a but &student[0] != &a. Just because student[0] and a have the same value does not mean that they have the same address. This is (I hope) obvious when a and student[0] are integers, but it's just as true when they are objects.

or even simpler int b = a;
